# how i can make button like this in windows forms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

How i can make this buttons with icons like these ??
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in order to create stylized buttons in `Winforms`, you have to work with the `Button.Image` property:

```
this.myButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
this.myButton.Image = // your image
// ...
```

The buttons in your image include a text, but since the enumeration `System.Windows.Forms.TextImageRelation` (used in the property `Button.TextImageRelation`) does not allow for a text below the image... obtaining the same style with this approach risks to become a hard task (using GDI, handling painting events, creating a derivative of the `Button` class, etc...), unless there is a trick that I don't know.

The fastest and simplest way to recreate the same style is to create a button with empty `Text` property and manually include the text in the image file. Actually, you set:

```
this.myButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
this.myButton.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
this.myButton.Text = "";
```

and you put this image (just an example) straight into the control:

[image: Button Image]

Comment: thank you   iam asked this question because i don't know how to include the text

Comment: As I said, you can set the text using the `Button.Text` property. But it will be tricky to obtain a text below the image using this approach. This is why I'm suggesting you to create an image that includes the text on the bottom, and then just create a button with no text and the image.